# Is there any Redis client source code which can be compiled by Visual C++ 6.0?

Tags: redis

I need to add redis support into a rather old c++ project, which is compiled by Visual C++ 6.0. However, "hiredis" seems not compatible with Visual C++ 6.0. Any other choices?

Comment: Seeing the Redis.io client site, your best bet would probably be to include one of the current C++ sources into your project.

Comment: The c++ client on redis.io requires boost. It is a bit complicated to add boost to that old project.